# MAILOSAUR_API_KEY not being read when added to cypress.json or <filename>config.json file

Tags: cypress

I am encountering an issue where in cypress returns an error: `You must set the CYPRESS_MAILOSAUR_API_KEY environment variable to use the Mailosaur plugin.`

I tried putting the `MAILOSAUR_API_KEY`to the cypress.json file and in the cypress.env.json. I think the `CYPRESS_MAILOSAUR_API_KEY` should be used for system environment variable, in this case is it required? or my variable in both cypress.json and env.json is just not being read? (my cypress.env.json file is in root level folder along with the cypress.json file)

**cypress.json file:**

```
{
    "baseUrl": "<base-url-here>",
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "MAILOSAUR_API_KEY": "<api-key-here>"
}
```

**cypress.env.json file:**

```
{
  "extends": "./cypress.json",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "MAILOSAUR_API_KEY": "<api-key-here>",
}
```

**commands.js**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("testMailosaur", (serverId, emailAddress) => {
  cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
    sentTo: emailAddress,
  }).then((email) => {
    expect(email.subject).to.equal("Test email address");
    return email.text.body
  });
});
```

**error details:**

```
You must set the CYPRESS_MAILOSAUR_API_KEY environment variable to use the Mailosaur plugin.

  18 |     if (!this.apiKey) {
  19 |       // CYPRESS_ prefix necessary per https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-3-CYPRESS
> 20 |       throw new Error('You must set the CYPRESS_MAILOSAUR_API_KEY environment variable to use the Mailosaur plugin.');
     | ^
  21 |     }
  22 | 
  23 |     return {
```

*Additional Info:*
I imported cypress-mailosaur in support/index.json via CommonJS syntax

```
import "./commands";
require("cypress-mailosaur");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I am using a config.json for my environment-variables and not cypress.env.json. That's why my current code does not work, since it is a config.json file and only extends cypress.json the syntax should be the same as how it should be implemented in cypress.json file wherein the `MAILOSAUR_API_KEY` should be inside the `env` object.

docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-1-configuration-file

```
{
  "extends": "./cypress.json",
  "env": {
    "MAILOSAUR_API_KEY": "<api-key-here>"
  },
  **other cypress env configs here**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have individual environment variables in Cypress there are mainly two options to configure them in files:

**1. Put them in the normal cypress.json configuration file**

Define them for the *env* key like:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
  "env": {
    "MAILOSAUR_API_KEY": "<api-key-here>"
  }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-1-configuration-file

**2. Put them in a dedicated cypress.env.json file**

```
{
  "MAILOSAUR_API_KEY": "<api-key-here>"
}
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-2-cypress-env-json

**Usage:**

The usage within your tests is the same in both cases:

```
Cypress.env('MAILOSAUR_API_KEY')
```

**Cypress Docs for Environment Variables:**
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables

Comment: Hi, I am currently using a config.json file for my environment variables, so I should have used the syntax the same with the cypress.json file which the "MAILOSAUR_API_KEY" should be inside the "env" object. Anyways this is fixed now. Thank you for sharing this!